# GLSL: reuse shader object

Tags: python, opengl, glsl

The [OpenGL 4.3 Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.core.20130214.pdf) states on page 79 that

> Multiple shader objects of the same type may be attached to a single program
>   object, and **a single shader object may be attached to more than one program object**.

Attaching a shader object to different program objects worked fine on an old Nvidia card but fails on a Radeon HD 7850.

Here is a sort-of-minimal example which I used to reproduce the error when linking the same shaders to two different programs:

```
#!/bin/env python3
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

def compile_shader(source, shadertype):
    shader = glCreateShader(shadertype)
    glShaderSource(shader, source)
    glCompileShader(shader)
    if not glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
        print(glGetShaderInfoLog(shader).decode())
    return shader

def link_program(*shaders):
    prog = glCreateProgram()
    for shader in shaders:
        glAttachShader(prog, shader)
    glLinkProgram(prog)
    glValidateProgram(prog)
    print(glGetProgramInfoLog(prog).decode())
    return prog

glutInit('')
glutInitContextVersion(4, 3)    
hwnd = glutCreateWindow(b'Shader Test')

print(glGetString(GL_VERSION).decode())

vtx_src = """#version 330 compatibility\nvoid main() { gl_Position = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1); }"""
frg_src = """#version 330 compatibility\nvoid main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1); }"""

v1 = compile_shader(vtx_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
f1 = compile_shader(frg_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
link_program(v1, f1)    # works
link_program(v1, f1)    # fails
```

Output:

```
4.3.12780 Core Profile Context 9.00.11
Validation successful.

Vertex shader(s) failed to link, fragment shader(s) failed to link.
Vertex link error: INVALID_OPERATION.
ERROR: 1:1: error(#132) Syntax error: "v" parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated

fragment link error: INVALID_OPERATION.
ERROR: 1:1: error(#132) Syntax error: "v" parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

The error message that the shader's sources are parsed during linking, which seems strange to me. After all, the shaders were successfully compiled (and also linked) before.

I tagged the question with Python, since my code example is using that language and this might be as well the cause of the problem...

Comment: Incidentally, this would not compile in either NV or AMD's GLSL implementations if they followed the specification correctly. Beginning with `#version 150`, `core` is assumed. In `core` GLSL, `gl_FragColor` is a removed built-in variable. Since your GLSL compiler is not compliant, you might as well be - write `#version 330 compatibility` if you are going to write to `gl_FragColor`. *Stricter GLSL compilers, such as Apple's or Mesa's will probably refuse to compile this.*

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that oversight. I use the builtins to keep shader sources short in the examples, but I did not think much about the profile because the shaders compiled (seemingly) correctly.

Comment: Using the compatibility profile in the shaders does not change the result.

Comment: I did not think it would, I was pointing out that compliant GLSL compilers interpret `#version 330` as `#version 330 core` and *should* complain about your use of `gl_FragColor`, which is undefined in `core`. Every vendor writes its own compiler, and since there have been no modern compliance tests from Khronos, they all do at least something wrong :P Often when a shader works on one vendor and not another it is actually not a driver bug, but a difference in how strictly one vendor complies vs. another. I am not saying that is the problem, but the original shader was doing something undefined.

Comment: Now, with all of that said... if you want to track down a strange parse error like this the best place to start would be to read-back the shader string GL is using. You can look into `glGetShaderSource (...)`. This is usually not an issue, but it could be considering you are using cross-language GL bindings. Things like character encoding and the way strings are natively represented (e.g. how the length is stored / computed) can do funny things to the string GL receives (which has strict rules that are similar to strings in C).

Comment: I shall try that given the opportunity. However what strikes me as strange is that the shaders are already compiled. Linking once works, but linking again fails. I don't see where parsing the source comes into play during linking.